# DynamoDB JSON formatting on AWS Lambda

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am retrieving a DynamoDB item using Python and AWS Lambda.  I am having difficulty parsing the value that the response contains.

For example, this is returned for response['Item']['GUID']

{u'S': u'8898f389-c282-4c4f-952a-87a0fbbb6d70'}

In the end, I just want the actual value without the extraneous information DynamoDB inserts.  How do you best handle DynamoDB's JSON formatting using Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an example:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

        print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

        if 'Records' not in event:
            print ('records not in event')
            return

        for record in event['Records']:
            if record['eventName'] == 'INSERT':
                print 'do something on insert'

            your_integer_hash_key = record['dynamodb']['Keys']['your_hash_key']['N']

            # if all image is stream
            if not 'NewImage' in record['dynamodb']:
                continue

            # get new image    
            new_image = record['dynamodb']['NewImage']
```

Comment: The tip to use json.dumps lead me to this:

`dynamo_GUID = json.dumps(response['Item']['GUID'])`

Everything seems to work how I anticipate now.